# Java Regular Expression byte by byte

Tags: java, regex, online-algorithm

I am looking for a way to incrementally apply a regular expression pattern, i.e. I am looking for a matcher which I can update with characters as they come in and which tells me on each character whether it is still matching or not.

Here is an illustration in code (`MagicMatcherIAmLookingFor` is the thing I am looking for, `characterSource` is something which I can query for new character, say an `InputStreamReader` for that matter):

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
final MagicMatcherIAmLookingFor incrementalMatcher = pattern.magic();
final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
char character;
while (characterSource.isNotEOF()) {
    character = characterSource.getNextCharacter();
    incrementalMatcher.add(character);
    if (incrementalMatcher.matches()) {
        stringBuilder.append(character);
    } else {
        return result(
             stringBuilder.toString(),
             remaining(character, characterSource)
        );
    }
}
```

I did not find a way to utilize the existing `java.util.regex.Pattern` like that, but maybe I just did not find it. Or is there an alternative library to the built in regular expressions which provides such a feature?

I did not have any luck searching the web for it - all the results are completely swamped with how to use java regular expressions in the first place.

I am targeting Java 8+

Comment: Thanks for the audit, corrected. Sloppy me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Is this the kind of object you are looking for ?

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class MagicMatcher {

    private Pattern pattern;
    private Matcher matcher;
    private String stringToCheck;

    public MagicMatcher(Pattern p , String s) {
        pattern = p;
        stringToCheck = s;
        updateMatcher();
    }

    public boolean matches() {
        return matcher.matches();
    }

    private void updateMatcher() {
        matcher = pattern.matcher(stringToCheck);
    }

    public void setStringToCheck(String s) {
        stringToCheck = s;
        updateMatcher();
    }

    public String getStringToCheck() {
        return stringToCheck;
    }

    public void addCharacterToCheck(char c) {
       stringToCheck += c;
       updateMatcher();
    }

    public void addStringToCheck(String s) {
        stringToCheck += s;
        updateMatcher();
    }

}
```